# Pastix installation

Tags: libraries

I'm trying to install Pastix library, but I'm still having problems with missing libraries and I'm really helpless now.

I started with copying `LINUX-GNU.in` as `config.in`, because I'm working on Lubuntu 15.04. I've changed paths to Scotch and Blas.

But now, when I try to `make examples_s`, it appears ok, but no compiled files appear in the `bin` folder.

When I try to make any other example, e.g. `make examples_z`, eventually I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
```

I know that Blas library couldn't be found, but I don't see the mistake I made. Blas libraries are located in my `/usr/lib` folder like this:

```
├── libblas
|     ├── libblas.so.3 -> libblas.so.3.0
|     └── libblas.so.3.0
├── libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
├── libblas.so.3gf -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3gf
├── libgslcblas.so.0 -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
└── libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
```

In `config.in` I've set `BLAS_HOME` variable like this:

```
BLAS_HOME=/usr/lib/libblas
```

So, do you know, what I'm doing wrong? I have no experience with Pastix and so I'm very confused right now.

---

### Solution

I've finally found out, that Pastix needs specifically `libblas.a` library.

So, the solution is:

1. Find the package which contains `libblas.a` - `apt-file search libblas.a`
2. Choose one of the packages - e.g. `libblas-dev`
3. Install the chosen package - `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev`

---

#### config.in

```
HOSTARCH    = i686_pc_linux
VERSIONBIT  = _32bit
EXEEXT      =
OBJEXT      = .o
LIBEXT      = .a
CCPROG      = gcc -Wall
CFPROG      = gfortran
CF90PROG    = gfortran -ffree-form
MCFPROG     = mpif90
CF90CCPOPT  = -ffree-form -x f95-cpp-input
# Compilation options for optimization (make expor)
CCFOPT      = -O3
# Compilation options for debug (make | make debug)
CCFDEB      = -g3
CXXOPT      = -O3
NVCCOPT     = -O3

LKFOPT      =
MKPROG      = make
MPCCPROG    = mpicc -Wall
MPCXXPROG   = mpic++ -Wall
CPP         = cpp
ARFLAGS     = ruv
ARPROG      = ar
EXTRALIB    = -lgfortran -lm -lrt
CTAGSPROG   = ctags

VERSIONMPI  = _mpi
VERSIONSMP  = _smp
VERSIONSCH  = _static
VERSIONINT  = _int
VERSIONPRC  = _simple
VERSIONFLT  = _real
VERSIONORD  = _scotch

###################################################################
#                  SETTING INSTALL DIRECTORIES                    #
###################################################################
# ROOT          = /home/osboxes/pastix
# INCLUDEDIR    = ${ROOT}/include
    # LIBDIR        = ${ROOT}/lib
# BINDIR        = ${ROOT}/bin
    # PYTHON_PREFIX = ${ROOT}

###################################################################
#                  SHARED LIBRARY GENERATION                      #
###################################################################
#SHARED=1
#SOEXT=.so
#SHARED_FLAGS =  -shared -Wl,-soname,__SO_NAME__
#CCFDEB       := ${CCFDEB} -fPIC
    #CCFOPT       := ${CCFOPT} -fPIC
#CFPROG       := ${CFPROG} -fPIC

###################################################################
#                          INTEGER TYPE                           #
###################################################################
# Uncomment the following lines for integer type support (Only 1)

#VERSIONINT  = _long
#CCTYPES     = -DFORCE_LONG -DINTSIZELONG
#---------------------------
#VERSIONINT  = _int32
#CCTYPES     = -DINTSIZE32
#---------------------------
#VERSIONINT  = _int64
#CCTYPES     = -DINTSSIZE64

###################################################################
#                           FLOAT TYPE                            #
###################################################################
CCTYPESFLT  =
# Uncomment the following lines for double precision support
VERSIONPRC  = _double
CCTYPESFLT := $(CCTYPESFLT) -DPREC_DOUBLE

# Uncomment the following lines for float=complex support
#VERSIONFLT  = _complex
#CCTYPESFLT := $(CCTYPESFLT) -DTYPE_COMPLEX


###################################################################
#                          MPI/THREADS                            #
###################################################################

# Uncomment the following lines for sequential (NOMPI) version
#VERSIONMPI  = _nompi
#CCTYPES    := $(CCTYPES) -DFORCE_NOMPI
    #MPCCPROG    = $(CCPROG)
#MCFPROG     = $(CFPROG)

# Uncomment the following lines for non-threaded (NOSMP) version
#VERSIONSMP  = _nosmp
#CCTYPES    := $(CCTYPES) -DFORCE_NOSMP

# Uncomment the following line to enable a progression thread,
#  then use IPARM_THREAD_COMM_MODE
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DPASTIX_THREAD_COMM

# Uncomment the following line if your MPI doesn't support MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE level,
#  then use IPARM_THREAD_COMM_MODE
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DPASTIX_FUNNELED

# Uncomment the following line if your MPI doesn't support MPI_Datatype correctly
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DNO_MPI_TYPE

# Uncomment the following line if you want to use semaphore barrier
# instead of MPI barrier (with IPARM_AUTOSPLIT_COMM)
#CCPASTIX    := $(CCPASTIX) -DWITH_SEM_BARRIER

# Uncomment the following lines to enable StarPU.
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) `pkg-config libstarpu --cflags` -DWITH_STARPU
    #EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) `pkg-config libstarpu --libs`
# Uncomment the correct 2 lines
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DCUDA_SM_VERSION=11
    #NVCCOPT    := $(NVCCOPT) -maxrregcount 32 -arch sm_11
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DCUDA_SM_VERSION=13
    #NVCCOPT    := $(NVCCOPT) -maxrregcount 32 -arch sm_13
CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DCUDA_SM_VERSION=20
    NVCCOPT    := $(NVCCOPT) -arch sm_20

# Uncomment the following line to enable StarPU profiling
# ( IPARM_VERBOSE > API_VERBOSE_NO ).
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DSTARPU_PROFILING

# Uncomment the following line to disable CUDA (StarPU)
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DFORCE_NO_CUDA

###################################################################
#                          Options                                #
###################################################################

# Show memory usage statistics
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DMEMORY_USAGE

# Show memory usage statistics in solver
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DSTATS_SOPALIN

# Uncomment following line for dynamic thread scheduling support
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DPASTIX_DYNSCHED

# Uncomment the following lines for Out-of-core
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DOOC -DOOC_NOCOEFINIT -DOOC_DETECT_DEADLOCKS

###################################################################
#                      GRAPH PARTITIONING                         #
###################################################################

# Uncomment the following lines for using metis ordering
#VERSIONORD  = _metis
#METIS_HOME  = ${HOME}/metis-4.0
    #CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DMETIS -I$(METIS_HOME)/Lib
    #EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) -L$(METIS_HOME) -lmetis

# Scotch always needed to compile
#SCOTCH_HOME ?= ${HOME}/scotch_5.1/
    SCOTCH_INC ?= /usr/include/scotch-int64  #$(SCOTCH_HOME)/include
SCOTCH_LIB ?= /usr/lib  #$(SCOTCH_HOME)/lib
    # Uncomment on of this blocks
    #scotch
    #CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -I$(SCOTCH_INC) -DWITH_SCOTCH
    #EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) -L$(SCOTCH_LIB) -lscotch -lscotcherrexit
    #ptscotch
    CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -I$(SCOTCH_INC) -DDISTRIBUTED -DWITH_SCOTCH
    #if scotch >= 6.0
    EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) -L$(SCOTCH_LIB) -lptscotch -lscotch -lptscotcherrexit
    #else
    #EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) -L$(SCOTCH_LIB) -lptscotch -lptscotcherrexit

###################################################################
#                Portable Hardware Locality                       #
###################################################################
# By default PaStiX uses hwloc to bind threads,
# comment this lines if you don't want it (not recommended)
HWLOC_HOME ?= /opt/hwloc/
HWLOC_INC  ?= $(HWLOC_HOME)/include
    HWLOC_LIB  ?= $(HWLOC_HOME)/lib
CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -I$(HWLOC_INC) -DWITH_HWLOC
EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) -L$(HWLOC_LIB) -lhwloc

###################################################################
#                             MARCEL                              #
###################################################################

# Uncomment following lines for marcel thread support
#VERSIONSMP := $(VERSIONSMP)_marcel
    #CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) `pm2-config --cflags` -I${PM2_ROOT}/marcel/include/pthread
    #EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) `pm2-config --libs`
# ---- Thread Posix ------
EXTRALIB   := $(EXTRALIB) -lpthread

# Uncomment following line for bubblesched framework support (need marcel support)
#VERSIONSCH  = _dyn
#CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DPASTIX_BUBBLESCHED

###################################################################
#                              BLAS                               #
###################################################################

# Choose Blas library (Only 1)
# Do not forget to set BLAS_HOME if it is not in your environnement
BLAS_HOME=/usr/lib/libblas
#----  Blas    ----
BLASLIB  = -lblas
#---- Gotoblas ----
#BLASLIB  = -L${BLAS_HOME} -lgoto
    #----  MKL     ----
    #Uncomment the correct line
    #BLASLIB  = -L$(BLAS_HOME) -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core
#BLASLIB  = -L$(BLAS_HOME) -lmkl_intel -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core
    #----  Acml    ----
    #BLASLIB  = -L$(BLAS_HOME) -lacml

###################################################################
#                             MURGE                               #
###################################################################
# Uncomment if you need MURGE interface to be thread safe
# CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DMURGE_THREADSAFE
    # Uncomment this to have more timings inside MURGE
    # CCPASTIX   := $(CCPASTIX) -DMURGE_TIME

###################################################################
#                          DO NOT TOUCH                           #
###################################################################

FOPT      := $(CCFOPT)
    FDEB      := $(CCFDEB)
CCHEAD    := $(CCPROG) $(CCTYPES) $(CCFOPT)
    CCFOPT    := $(CCFOPT) $(CCTYPES) $(CCPASTIX)
CCFDEB    := $(CCFDEB) $(CCTYPES) $(CCPASTIX)
    NVCCOPT   := $(NVCCOPT) $(CCTYPES) $(CCPASTIX)

###################################################################
#                        MURGE COMPATIBILITY                      #
###################################################################

MAKE     = $(MKPROG)
    CC       = $(MPCCPROG)
CFLAGS   = $(CCFOPT) $(CCTYPESFLT)
FC       = $(MCFPROG)
    FFLAGS   = $(CCFOPT)
LDFLAGS  = $(EXTRALIB) $(BLASLIB)
CTAGS    = $(CTAGSPROG)
```

Comment: This is a question best asked on the Pastix mailing lists of forums.

Comment: I've tried to, but question there must be approved by admin before going public and unfortunately, nobody has reacted.

Comment: Have you tried the [public forums](https://gforge.inria.fr/forum/?group_id=186)? They seem to be more active.

Comment: @ChristianClason I have, nobody has reacted.